# Where does the flow of power come from for a Transmutation Circle to work?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

On the Full Metal Alchemist Wiki under the Category  Alchemy. It says this...

> The circle itself is a conduit which focuses and dictates the flow of
>   power, tapping into the energies that already exist within the earth
>   and matter. It represents the cyclical flow of the world's energies
>   and phenomena and turns that power to manipulable ends.

But does this energy not come from a parallel world on the other side of the gate where alchemy took a different form of science? Did it not come from the lives of those who died in that world? Or is this different in FMA Brotherhood, because I am certain this is what Hohenhiem told Edward in the FMA Anime (2003).

Answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: it is different in Brotherhood as Father (Dwarf) taught Alchemy to the people of Amestris in a way where he could shut down all Alchemy himself (as if he was god), Xing's alchemy called Alkahestry which Von Hohenhiem taught operates differently so even after Father shut down everyone's Alchemy, May could still use her Alkahestry to help the Elric's escape

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, It's different. The original FMA anime didn't wait around for the manga to catch up (like DBZ did), so it diverged instead.

What you ended up with was 2 completely different endings, and 2 different explanations for why alchemy works:

- In the original anime, the explanation was that It came from the other side of the gate.
- In the manga and in brotherhood, it came from energy that was already in the earth.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Alkahestry (the other form of alchemy from a different country called Xing) was powered by this thing called the 'Dragons pulse' (essentially tectonic movement) and the Father's philosopher's stone powered alchemy in Amestris, at least in *Brotherhood* it did.

Comment: *Regular* alchemy was powered by tectonic movement. That's why Father, who controlled the tectonic movements within Amestris, was able to "turn off" the Elric's powers, but Scar's and May's powers (which derive from alkehestry) were unaffected. We don't know how alkahestry is powered, it's never really explained other than it comes from the "dragon's pulse", as you mentioned.